# Content Security Policy in ReactJS app on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, material-ui, content-security-policy

Now i ran into such a time consuming error. My CSP policy includes errors and i've tried to remove them but all in vain.
Its a reactjs running on Heroku under an expressjs application. So my folder structure is;

```
ExpressApp
       |-client_folder
           |-Reactjs-App
```

I use a [react-csp npm-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csp) to set the CSP policy and actually confirmed that its writing the policy on heroku post-build. React-csp tells us to create a csp.json file and mine looks as follows.

```
{
    "prod": {
            "default-src": "'self'", 
            "script-src" : ["'self'"],
            "font-src":["'self'", "*" ],
            "style-src": [ "'self'", "https://*.googleapis.com", "'unsafe-line'" ],
            "connect-src": ["'self'",  "*"],
            "img-src" : ["'self'",  "*"]
        }
}
```

After i upload the app with git push heroku master, and visit the site, i see it loaded without any styles. And when i check the console, i see this snapshot.
[image]
I'm using [Material-UI](https://mui.com/) in my project plus all its fonts but it can't seem to include everything i need in the CSP policy. I really need help because i've been stuck on this problem for a while now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's `unsafe-inline` not `unsafe-line`

Comment: I've just tried it out but still getting the errors in the console.

Comment: What i tried out was basically to change the "'unsafe-line'" to "unsafe-line". So that is  "style-src": [ "'self'", "https://*.googleapis.com", "unsafe-line" ], but i still got same errors list

Comment: it's `unsafe-inline` not `unsafe-line`

Comment: @Alghazali505 do you really think it is correct to post a completely wrong answer, and then [spoof it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70195871/revisions) basing on my answer, using the fact that your answer was earlier in time? After I pointed out that your answer was absolutely wrong.

Comment: @Alghazali505 that's not true. At 8:21 SO showed you a message about posting my answer, it's a buil-in SO feature. As your comment shown, you "noticed the error" only at 8:25, after my answer where I pointed that you gave a wrong answer. Ok, even you helped Hakim Marley in comments, but question is: *why did you spoofed your real answer by making mine  answer a duplicate?*

Comment: I didn't spoof your answer, deal with it.

Comment: I always edit my answers when I try different solutions, you can check my other answers.

Comment: You could've stated politely that your answer was first, and for sure I will not mind who will take the mark.. and remember your answer was marked before mine.. someone changed his mind.

Comment: Visitors didn't hire you to speak for them, So unless you're the UX Researcher here it's not up to you what annoys the visitor.

Answer (score -1):

Errors in the console you showed said that you use wrong token `'unsafe-line'` in the `style-src` directive. Change in to `'unsafe-inline'`.

Note that single quotes are mandatory for `'self'` and `'unsafe-inline'`.